# Issue with Sliding Up/Down a Hidden Div using .toggle()

Tags: jquery, easing

Can you please take a look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/CGbCv/1/) sample which I am trying to create a smooth animate of hidden div from down to up on mouse hover. As you can see the div appears from left down corner but I would like to animate it from bottom to top. I tried to use animate() but I didn't know how to change the hidden div statue from hidden?
here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#handler').hover(function(){$('#hidden').toggle(1000)});
});​
```

Can you please let me know how i can use  jQuery easing  plugin for something like this? 
 Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `slideToggle` instead of `toggle`

http://jsfiddle.net/CGbCv/2/

The `.slideToggle()` method animates the height of the matched elements. This causes lower parts of the page to slide up or down, appearing to reveal or conceal the items. If the element is initially displayed, it will be `hidden;` if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed `inline`. When the height reaches 0 after a hiding animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do this without toggling?! I mean as you notice as when as user mouse out from the handler div the hidden div disappears now how we can keep the div available after mouseout of the hidden div? I hope I explained enough what I mean?!